# Eclipse installation in Win8.1

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I am trying to install Eclipse in Win8.1 but it gives me all various kinds of errors. I installed JRE and JDK and this is what I get as an error when I am trying to run Eclipse. Any idea how this should be fixed?

Update: I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2X7TxNOzu_I) and changed my eclipse.ini file to the following but still I get the same error:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is with the newer version of java. Uninstall Java and then download and install jdk-8u25 version and set the path

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java - they must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: @Aqarain can you please take a look at the update? Also can you give me a link to where I should install that jdk? I just installed it from Oracle website. Thanks. My jdk version is jdk1.8.0_45

Comment: @greg-449 I installed the 64bit version from the Oracle website. Here's the names of the file I installed: jdk-8u45-windows-i586 and jre-8u45-windows-i586

Comment: I would suggest you to uninstall java and then download jdk-8u25 from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u25-oth-JPR    and install. Most probably it will solve the problem

Comment: @Aqarain so I uninstalled all the Java I had and installed what you told me. I yet have the same error. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: R u setting the variable in environment variables? if yes then plz go through this http://www.ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/